# How can we use every "current row" value as condition argument in aggregation expression

Tags: r

I want to generate a corresponding value (in the new last column) by aggregating my table by sum conditions, which some of each corresponding row values are used at this conditions and calculations:

Example:

[image: My problem described in this picture:]

Sum of all "Second"s, if "First"'s equal to current First value (A) and "second"s equal to current Second value (5)

At Excel, We address the current row by using it's address easily and by extending formula by dragging. At poweBI/DAX we use EARLIER function to refer to current row value. I don't know what should I do in R.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute group sums by both variables First and Second.

```
df$C <- with(df, ave(Second, First, Second, FUN = sum))
df

#   First Second  C
# 1     A      5 10
# 2     A     10 10
# 3     B      5 10
# 4     B     10 20
# 5     B     10 20
# 6     B      5 10
# 7     A      5 10
```

---

`dplyr` form

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(First, Second) %>%
  mutate(C = sum(Second))
```

Or

```
df %>%
  group_by(First, Second) %>%
  add_tally(Second, name = "C")
```

***Data***

```
df <- data.frame(First = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A"),
                 Second = c(5, 10, 5, 10, 10, 5, 5))
```

---

***Edit*** *(Additional question from the comment)*

Sum of all "Second"s, if "First" is equal to current First value and "Second"s GREATER than current Second value:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_by(First) %>%
  mutate(D = map_dbl(Second, ~ sum(Second[Second > .])))

#   First Second     D
#   <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A          5    10
# 2 A         10     0
# 3 B          5    20
# 4 B         10     0
# 5 B         10     0
# 6 B          5    20
# 7 A          5    10
```

Comment: Thank you Darren.
and what should I do if I want to calculate:
Sum of all "Second"s, if "First"'s equal to current First value (A) and "second"s GREATER than current Second value (5)
?

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` solution:

What you described is basicaly sum of all *Second* values for every unique pair of *First* and *Second*. Hence, we can simply group them together and compute totals inside every group:

```
# required library
library(dplyr)

df %>%
# grouping unique pairs of values of 'First' and 'Second'
  group_by(First, Second) %>%
# computing sum of 'Second' within created groups
  mutate(C = sum(Second))
```